# Missing Observations in Zonal Statistics Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, missing-data

I am using zonal statistical tools. I have field boundary shapefile which has 1,062,063 observations.

I am using zonal statistical as table tool to obtain precipitation values from raster layer. when I run the tool, the output table only provide 1,003,273 observations.

I guess there are 58,790 missing observations.

Do you have any ideas why there are missing observations and how I can fix these missing observations?

Comment: Have the same problem. Hope that someone can help